# Batch copy and rename multiple files

Tags: bash

I would like to batch copy and rename all files from a directory, recursively.

I have something like this:

```
/dir/subdir/file.aa
/dir/subdir/fileb.aa
/dir/filec.aa
```

and would like all files to be copied as this:

```
/newdir/1.xx
/newdir/2.xx
/newdir/3.xx
/newdir/4.xx
```

..
/newdir/nn.xx

How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sth. like this:

```
num=0
for i in `find -name "*.aa"`; do
    let num=num+1
    cp $i newdir/$lc.xx
done
```

Comment: Thanks, instead of using num=num+1 I had to use num=$((num+1)).

Comment: This solution does not handle all file names the way they should be. If a file has a space or similiar in it, it fails.

Comment: Instead of `num=$(( num+1))`, you can simply do `(( num++ ))`.

Answer (score 5):

```
find -name "*.aa" | cat -n | while read n f; do
    cp "$f" newdir/"$n".xx
done
```

will work with (nearly) any valid filename (except if you have newlines in it, which would be allowed as well).

If you are not restricted to the shell, another solution in python could be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import os
    import shutil
    target = sys.argv[1]
    for num, source in enumerate(sys.argv[2:]):
        shutil.move(source, os.path.join(target, "%d.xx" % num))
```

which then could be called as

```
<script name> newdir *.aa
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this, but this might not be the optimal solution, since there are many tools that could be used for this.

My way of solving this problem would be to write a function and then apply this function to every file in the directory/subdirectories. Assuming that you have multiple cores/processors and that your function would be doing something more CPU consuming than just renaming and copying files you would also parallelize the task.

The bash script would look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
n=1
CopyAndRename() {
   NEWNAME=$n.xx
   cp "$i" /newdir/$NEWNAME 
   n=$[$n+1]
}

IFS=$'\n'
LIST=`find /dir -type f`

for i in $LIST; do
   CopyAndRename $i
done
```

This should also handle filenames with whitespaces and other special characters. For parallelization you could use a program prll and then replace the for loop with

```
prll CopyAndRename $LIST
```

But this really isn't necessary for renaming and copying.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it will look like this:

```
 find ... | parallel cp {} /newdir/{#}.xx
```

It will do this in parallel (one job per core) which may speed up the copying - depending on your storage system.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel